# Passing additional parameters using $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

In my AngularJS app I have one template and one controller that I can reach via 2 different url:

```
$routeProvider.when('/site/contents/:obj/:parent/:isnew?', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/site/data.html',
    resolve: {
        loggedin: checkLoggedin
    }
});

$routeProvider.when('/site/contents/new-obj', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/site/data.html',
    resolve: {
        loggedin: checkLoggedin
    }
});
```

The second route should statically set a parameter isnew=1, as I would do using a RewriteRule in apache, but looking at the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider it seems impossible to do.

Anyone had encountered the same question?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really set default route parameters in Angular, if that is what you are trying to do.

The best idea would probably be to check in your controller if `$routeParams.isnew` is set and, if not, default it to 1.

Angular routes are supposed to be fairly simple rather than being heavily pattern based like RewriteEngine in apache, so the logic should be in your controller.

Your controller could look like so:

```
function($routeParams) {
    $scope.isNew = ($routeParams.isnew || 1);
}
```

In your case, you can probably even get away with having no `isnew` param. Use the first route for modifying existing objects and the second for creating them (so the existence of `obj` in the params defines if it is new or not).

Comment: Well, it's not that simple, because even in the first route I could have isnew != 1 that's why I use that parameter. I currently removed the second route and I'm using just one route passing the string "(empty)" as obj parameter, but that's not what I call a "clean" solution, because I don't like having "rules" or conventions inside my code.

Comment: Does your first route get used to create an object associated with that particular `obj` and `parent`, whereas the second creates one associated with nothing?

Logic in your controller would still be the way to go, either way.

Comment: The first route is used when the user has already selected all the parameters I need, the second route is used when the user has not already selected those parameter and he/she will do it directly on the page (data.html). Maybe a solution would be to check if obj is empty, in that case isnew would implicitly true. Again, not what I called a clean solution.

Comment: the most correct solution then would be to check in your controller if said parameters have been selected (so, `obj` and `parent`?). If not, this is a completely new one and they are required to enter them. A conditional or two won't really make it 'dirty'.

Comment: Well, yes it's not really 'dirty' it's just that I had in mind what I had done using the Rewrite engine. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.